# Replace file does not work in Helhum upload example

Tags: upload, typo3, extbase

I use the [Helhum upload example](https://github.com/helhum/upload_example) to upload pdf files. The first upload works fine. But when I try to edit the record and replace the previously uploaded file, I get the following error: "The identity property "xxx.pdf" is no UID. I am using TYPO3 9.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Check this pull request: https://github.com/GhanshyamBhava/imageuploader

Comment: The link does not work. Do you mean https://github.com/GhanshyamBhava/upload_example ?

Comment: Yes! Also here is another MR: https://github.com/helhum/upload_example/pull/37

Comment: Okay. This example works almost. But you still can't replace an existing picture. But the solution described here fixed the upload: https://github.com/helhum/upload_example/issues/28